# create progresbar percentage in angular 9

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

i want to create a progressbar in angular 9 when the image selected for upload .

i waite this code for find upload file and show me percent of uload .

```
 let elemnt = document.getElementById('progress');

 this.managersService.UpdateWithFile(editModel, this.personalInfo.id, '/Manager/PersonalInfo').subscribe(
      (upload: HttpEvent<any>) => {
        switch (upload.type) {
          case HttpEventType.UploadProgress:
            if (upload.total) {
              this.queueProgress = Math.round(upload.loaded / upload.total * 100);
              if (this.queueProgress <= 100 && this.queueProgress > 0) {
                elemnt.style.strokeDashoffset = 440 + 45 + 'px'
                this.cdRef.detectChanges();
              }
            }
            break;
          case HttpEventType.Response:
            if (upload.body['isSuccess']) {
              this.queueProgress = null;
              this.alertService.success('', upload.body['message']);
              this.router.navigate(['/managers']);
            } else {
              this.cdRef.detectChanges();
            }
            this.loading = false;
            this.queueProgress = null;
            break;
        }
      },
      error => {
        this.loading = false;
        this.queueProgress = null;
      });
  }
```

in this line i get a percent and need the change `HTML` px size .

```
if (this.queueProgress <= 100 && this.queueProgress > 0) {
                elemnt.style.strokeDashoffset = 440 + 45 + 'px'
                this.cdRef.detectChanges();
              }
```

but my problem is here ,this code just once time exceuted `elemnt.style.strokeDashoffset = 440 + 45 + 'px'` but i need to every time the `queueProgress` changed value , this line going to excecute .

i using this `this.cdRef.detectChanges();` but it not worked . whats the problem ? how can i solve this ????

Comment: where did you declare elmnt?

Comment: @AakashGarg let elemnt = document.getElementById('progress');

Answer (score 0):

You are setting on each HttpEvent the offset to `485px` (440 + 45) and forgot to use your variable `this.queueProgress` instead. This is why you don't see any change. As its percentage you could calculate this by multiplying with your required max offset

```
const maxOffset = 100;
elemnt.style.strokeDashoffset = 440 + (maxOffset * this.queueProgress / 100) + 'px'
```